# What does the -P option do to mount?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat, mount, options

I'm migrating from an archaic version of Red Hat to Ubuntu 9.  When going through my old nfs mount script, I found that it contained the -P option.

So my script looks like:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o -P ...
```

It looks like the -P is one of the -o options.  My question is: what does the -P option do?  I've searched every man page I can find, with no luck.  Could it have to do with privileged ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the FreeBSD man page for [mount_nfs](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mount_nfs&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE) says:

> -P
>         Use a reserved socket port number.  This flag is obsolete, and
>            only retained for compatibility reasons.  (For the rare case
>            where the client has a trusted root account but untrustworthy
>            users and the network cables are in secure areas this does help,
>            but for normal desktop clients this does not apply.)